# Error when start a container

Tags: docker

I tried to run a simple container and got the error message

```
docker run docker/whalesay boo
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 843b258e583b1e9966dc9b771f613e60b887ecc2059376473e06ede68e1bd347: [8] System error: exec: "boo": executable file not found in $PATH
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to execute "boo" as a command inside the container. You actually want to run the `cowsay` program inside the container, and pass boo to *that*:

```
$ docker run docker/whalesay cowsay boo
 _____ 
< boo >
 ----- 
    \
     \
      \     
                    ##        .            
              ## ## ##       ==            
           ## ## ## ##      ===            
       /""""""""""""""""___/ ===        
  ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~   
       \______ o          __/            
        \    \        __/             
          \____\______/
```